# Pushing notifications from one Viewcontroller to another in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to push a notification from one(1st) ViewController to (2nd)Another ViewController while this notification takes a function of the first ViewController and prints the result of the function. How can I do that? Please help, I searched all the internet with no result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Post Notification: (First ViewController)

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil, userInfo: ["key":"value"])
```

Get Notification: (Second ViewController)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.ReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

Method to handle received Notification:

```
@objc func ReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){

    //Take Action on Notification

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily make use of protocols to pass the data between controller same as observer

**Step 1** Create a protocol stub

```
 /// Protcol 
    @objc protocol showViews : class {
        /// An optional func inside protocol that will
        /// be used to pass the required Data
        /// For now, I am just passing a Bool Value
        @objc optional func showToggleMenu(needToShow:Bool)
    }
```

**Source ViewController** - Controller from which data is to be passed

```
/// Source Controller
class mainHomeVC: UIViewController 
{
   /// Create a referencing object for the protocol
   var delegate : showViews?


    /// To pass data just call the delegate and its function
    @IBAction func showToggleMenu(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        /// Pass Data
        delegate?.showToggleMenu!(needToShow: true)
    }
}
```

**Destination Controller** Controller in which Data was required to be passed

```
/// Destination Controller
class homeVC: UIViewController 
{
   /// Create a reference of class from which data is to be fetched
   private lazy var mainHomeVCObjet: mainHomeVC =
    {
        // Instantiate View Controller
        let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainHomeVC") as! mainHomeVC
        viewController.delegate = self
        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.addChildViewController(viewController)
        return viewController
    }()
}

//MARK: Protocol Extension
extension homeVC : showViews
{
    //MARK: Show Side Menu ?
    func showToggleMenu(needToShow: Bool)
    {
        if (needToShow)
        {
            print("time to show a toggle Menu")
        }
    }
}
```